# Angular, Loop through already created components on the DOM

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm pretty new to angular, but I have managed to get most of the concepts down. However, I can't seem to figure out how I should go about solving my issue.

I have one component, that has other components as its children. I want to be able to loop through the child components, and add data to them separately, either before they are rendered, or after they are rendered.

The master component is an HTML version of a government form, and I have scattered throughout it a simple component that is supposed to display text from a database relevant to the field it is in.

If I was using something like jQuery, I would just attach an id to each component, and loop through them, adding data if the component id matches the key of the JSON object.

Is there any standard way to do something like this with angular?

Comment: See https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren and also https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChildren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be better off "binding" any information you'd like to provide to your child components instead of implementing a vanilla/jQuery solution that involves querying the DOM and then manually manipulating the DOM.

Take a look at [property-binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-property) and [two-way binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#basics-of-two-way-binding).

Here's a quick example:

```html
<my-child-component [someProperty]="myValue"></my-child-component>

<my-menu-component [menu]="menuData"></my-menu-component>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This is really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You probably should rethink the way you are trying to do it, when you start with Angular you need to leave a lot of concept that you learnt in jQuery behind.

We don't manipulate the DOM directly in Angular, we manipulate the data that is bound to the template and that binding is what updates the DOM.

Tom added an answer as I was typing, he is saying what I was going to.

Answer (score 0):

The angular way to achieve what you want is to use one-way data binding. Check out the example in the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/Input).

In the example they have a child component in the template html of the app.

```
<bank-account bankName="RBC" account-id="4747"></bank-account>
```

You can one-way bind data by referencing a public property on the parent and using the square bracket syntax to indicate one-way binding like so:

```
<bank-account [bankName]="somePropertyOnTheParent" [account-id]="someOtherPropertyOnTheParent"></bank-account>
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot!